# Pasar Variable Angular Material MatDialog -

Tags: angular, angular-material

quiero consultar algo sobre lo que se ven consultas. Yo estoy empezando con angular y no encontré mi busqueda especificamente.
Lo que tengo aqui es un caso del despliegue de una serie de todos los productos que están en una base de datos local, donde muestro , algunas propiedades basicas en la Card. Para mostrar más detalles lo quiero hacer en un modal. Cómo deberia completarse para yo poder en el modal recibir  una variable de la Card, supongo que debería ser el product.id y a partir de ahi mostrar las propiedades que me interesen de la misma base.
El nombre 'Juan' pasa bien.

home-product.component.ts

```
    import { Component, Inject, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { productsDB } from '../../shared/data/products';
    import { HomeChildComponent } from '../home-child/home-child.component';
    import {MatDialogModule, MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';


    export interface DialogData {
      name: string;
      price: any;
      id:any;
   }

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home-products',
      templateUrl: './home-products.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home-products.component.scss']
    })

    export class HomeProductsComponent implements OnInit {
      products = [];
        name: string;

      dialogRef: MatDialogRef<HomeChildComponent>;

      constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { 
        this.products = productsDB.Product; 
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
      }
       product : []

      openDialog(product?) : void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(HomeChildComponent, {
          width: '250px',
          data: { name: product ? product.name : '',id : product ? product.id : '',price : product ? product.price : '',
          }
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log('The dialog was closed');

        });
      }
    }
```

home-products.component.html

```
        <div *ngFor="let product of products">
        <mat-card class="ll-product">
          <mat-card-content>
            <div>
            <a [routerLink]="['/products', product.id]">{{ product.name }}</a>
            </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <div>
          <mat-icon>star</mat-icon> {{ product.rating }}/5
        </div>
        <div>
          <button (click)="openDialog(product)">Más Detalles</button>
        </div>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

home-child.component.ts

```
  import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {DialogData} from '../home-products/home-products.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-child',
  templateUrl: './home-child.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./home-child.component.css']
})
export class HomeChildComponent implements OnInit {
  products = [];

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<HomeChildComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,

  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

home-child.component.html

```
   <h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
   <h1 mat-dialog-title > {{data.id}}</h1>
   <h1 mat-dialog-title > {{data.price}}</h1>
   <h1 mat-dialog-title ></h1>
   <div mat-dialog-actions>
     <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">close</button>
   </div>
```

shared/data/ productos.ts

```
export class productsDB {
    private static _Product = [
      {
        id: 1,
        sucursales: :["Buenos Aires","Neuquen","La Pampa","Las Toninas"],
        images: ['assets/images/productodestacado.jpg'],
        name: 'Producto destacado',
        price: 5000.0,
        rating: 4.8,
        feedback: 3,
        category: 'digitalization',
        tags: ['Diesel', 'Hudson', 'Lee'],
        empresa: 'OceanPacific'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        sucursales:["San Luis","San Juan","Santa Cruz","San Antonio Oeste"],
        images: ['assets/images/productobarato.jpg'],
        name: 'producton barato',
        price: 4000.0,
        rating: 3.5,
        feedback: 3,
        category: 'encuadernacion',
        tags: ['Diesel', 'Hudson', 'Lee'],
        empresa: 'Empresa Lider Industrial'
      }
],
```

Gracias

Comment: Estas seguro que antes de abrir el matdialog tiene datos  `product.id` porque cuando mandes la información desde el matdialog debes de declararla como tienes las anteriores y mandarla a llamar como this.data.idProducto, si es que le pones  asi `data: { name: 'Juan', animal: this.animal, price: this.price, idProducto: this.product.id},`

Comment: Hola Enrique, gracias por tu respuesta. Ya resolí el pasar las variables. Edité la pregunta.